# adding two float dtype numbers that are stored in dictionary is giving me a wrong answer. Can someone pls explain why?

Tags: python, dictionary

Here is my program and output. Note: I was doing this in a jupyter notebook.[program img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPkfQ.png)

shop_prices = {'apple':1.4,'eggs':1.7,'rice':1}
shop_prices['apple']+shop_prices['eggs']

Output:
3.0999999999999996

I was expecting the reseult to be 3.1